# RenderBox error when I have my ListView inside of an expanded

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I have followed the other solutions where users place a ListView into an expanded and then place the expanded into SizedBox, and then place the SizedBox into a row. I am still getting the Render box error.

> The method '>' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
>
> > (1e-10) The relevant error-causing widget was:    Row

the code is:

```
 return new Row(children: [
              new Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: ListView(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: getPostItems(snapshot),
              ))
              )]);
```

I would like the height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double.infinity` is used to make the length of an element the same as the parent´s. In the example, the `SizedBox` is trying to be the same width as the `Row`, which is a Widget that expands according to the child, which has an infinite width. Try this:

```
Expanded(
  child: Container( // This way, the Container should fit into a non infinite width or height, but rather the dimensions of the remaining space of another widget
    child: ListView(
      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: getPostItems(snapshot),
    )
  )
)
```